# Populating error message with field name in Parsley js

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I couldn't find anything in the Parsley docs or in Google.
Is there an easy way to set an attribute in input and populate the error message with custom message.

For example:

```
<label>First name
<input type="text" required/>
</label>
```

with give a standard error "This value is required." 

But it would be nice to have something like

```
<label>First name
<input type="text" required data-parsley-field-name="Last name"/>
</label>
```

with error like "Last name is required"

Or as an option, just grad string from`<label>`.

I know that I can set custom messages, but you have to do it on each input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will your job

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="phone" class="form" data-err="last name" value="" class="required" data-parsley-required="" />
<input type="text" name="phone" class="form" data-err="First name" value="" class="required" data-parsley-required="" />
<input type="submit" value="Go">
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").parsley();

    $.listen('parsley:field:error', function(){
                var i = 0;
    $("#myForm .form").each(function(k,e){
    var field = $(e).data("err");
    $(e).next("ul").find("li:eq("+i+")").html(field+" is required");
        });
    });
});
```

here is working fiddle **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/kuJPL/43/)**

Comment: I know about this, as I mentioned. This require to set custom messages for each input, thus unnecessary repeating.

Comment: in your case you will also need to repeat the data-parsley-field-name for each input, then why don't you use the custom messages.?

Comment: i have updated my answer for you, This will know do your job. :)

Comment: thanks, I'm thinking something about just set up a custom default messages  (may be via language file or directly in parsley.js) and sent messages like "%f is required" and then do some magic to automatically bind the messages from attributes or label.